# Distributed transactions in microservices

Tags: microservices, distributed-transactions, saga

I have 2 microservices `S1` and `S2`. `S1` invokes `S2` to update a data and then `S1` inserts another data,But let's consider `S1` fails,Then we need to rollback the data updated by `S2` or else we'll be in inconsistent state.

I also gone through Saga patterns.will it satisfy this inconsistency

Can anyone suggest any better solutions for this?

Answer (score 4):

Distributed transactions are problematic for most circumstances and they are bad for services

- Service Boundary – service boundary is a trust boundary. Atomic
  transactions require holding locks and holding them on behalf of
  foreign service is opening a security hole (makes it much easier to
  do a denial of service attack) You cannot assume atomicity between
  two different entities or resources. Esp. when these resources belong
  to different businesses.
- Transactions introduce tight coupling both temporal and operational
- Transactions hinder scalability – It isn’t that you can’t scale
  but it is much harder

Sagas (which, by the way, do not necessitate orchestration) emerged as a solution for coordination because they allow services to be more flexible - and are in fact closer to how real life work. Another pattern you can combine with Sagas to help with delaying effects can be [reservation](https://www.infoq.com/news/2009/09/reservations).

Another option you have might be reconsidering how you partitioned your services. It might be that the service boundaries you have now are not correct and a redesign will contain the needed transaction into one service

Answer (score 2):

I think Saga pattern (Orchestration) enables an application to maintain data consistency across multiple services without using distributed transactions.

This solution has the following drawbacks:

The programming model is more complex. For example, a developer must design compensating transactions that explicitly undo changes made earlier in a saga.

There are also the following issues to address:

In order to be reliable, a service must atomically update its database and publish an event. It cannot use the traditional mechanism of a distributed transaction that spans the database and the message broker.

Answer (score 0):

If both `S1` and `S2` are "under your control", than you are much better off designing them in a way that doesn't require distributed transactions. After all, microservices are supposed to be *independent* services. They are obviously not independent, if they must share a transaction.

If only one of those is under your control and the other one isn't, then the simplest way is to order the calls in a way that won't require a rollback on the service that is not under your control. If you are lucky, you might even order calls in a way that don't require any rollbacks, not even in your service. Remember, you don't have to solve distributed transactions in general, just solve the actual use-case you face!